# can we deploy a container into a specific node in a docker swarm

Tags: linux, docker, docker-swarm

I have a docker swarm cluster, it contains 1 master 3 nodes. When we deploy a container through swarm master, e.g with the below command

```
docker -H tcp://<master_ip>:5001 run -dt --name swarm-test busybox /bin/sh
```

Swarm will auto pick a node and deploy my container. Is there a way to hand pick a node? e.g I want to deploy a container in node 1.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Take a look at the Swarm [filter](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/node_ls/#filtering) docs. You can set various constraints on what node Swarm should pick for any given container. For your case try something like:

```
docker run ... -e constraint:node==node1 ...
```

This would start the container on `node1`.

Comment: what is "node1"? a hostname..? i need to actually start it on node1 but docker doesn't understand what is node1

Comment: ok so it's first part of hostname actually so I had to extract it with terraform: maybe someone will be interested:   `sudo docker --tls -H ${aws_instance.master.0.private_ip}:2376 node update --label-add name=slave-${count.index} ${element(split(".", self.private_dns), 0)}`

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#set-service-mode-mode

Comment: Reference docs: [Placement Constraints](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/services/#placement-constraints) and [Compose File Constraints](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/deploy/#placement)

Answer (score 1):

Simple nginx example (using hostname of server)

```
docker service create --publish {serverPort}:80 --constraint "node.hostname == {hostName}" --name {serviceName} nginx:latest
```