# Docker Swarm Mode - Show containers per node

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I am using Docker version 17.12.1-ce.

I have set up a swarm with two nodes, and I have a stack running on the manager, while I am to instantiate new nodes on the worker (not within a service, but as stand-alone containers).

So far I have been unable to find a way to instantiate containers on the worker specifically, and/or to verify that the new container actually got deployed on the worker.

I have read the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36609890/can-we-deploy-a-container-into-a-specific-node-in-a-docker-swarm) which led me to run containers with the `-e` option specifying `constraint:Role==worker`, `constraint:node==<nodeId>` or `constraint:<custom label>==<value>`, and this [github issue from 2016](https://github.com/docker/swarm/issues/2141) showing the `docker info` command outputting just the information I would need (i.e. how many containers are on each node at any given time), however I am not sure if this is a feature of the ***stand-alone*** swarm, since `docker info` only the number of nodes, but **no detailed info for each node**. I have also tried with `docker -D info`.

Specifically, I need to:

- Manually specify which node to deploy a *stand-alone* container to (i.e. not related to a service).
- Check that a container is running on a specific swarm node, or check how many containers are running on a node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swarm commands will only care/show service-related containers. If you create one with `docker run`, then you'll need to use something like `ssh node2 docker ps` to see all containers on that node.

I recommend you do your best in a Swarm to have all containers as part of a service. If you need a container to run on nodeX, then you can create a service with a "node constraint" using labels and constraints. In this case you could restrict the single replica of that service to a node's hostname.

`docker service create --constraint Node.Hostname==swarm2 nginx`

To see all tasks on a node from any swarm manager:

`docker node ps <nodename_or_id>`

Comment: My issue here is related to launching certain stateful nodes that would not benefit too much from being part of a same service (e.g. replication, automatic restart and address resolution by service name). It does feel somewhat dirty to create a service unit for each container I need just to let the swarm distribute containers and/or impose placement constraints (my second node would be part of a pool of nodes all eligible for deploy), but I guess that is like some overhead related to Swarm Mode, think in terms of service rather than container. Thank you for your answer, marked as correct.